# set precision c#

Tags: c#, rounding, precision

Is it possible to set precision of double values in c# for all double values included in the project? I have a lot of values there and changing them with Math.Round would be exhausting. I need to have the double value as 5.12345 instead of 5.123455123321321 for example.

Comment: No... but you can set the precision when you print them out to text, or you can add an extension method to the `double` class.

Comment: A double has double precision as defined by the standard, and you can’t change that. What you can change is the format when you print or otherwise output your double.

Comment: Shouldn't `5.123455123321321` round to `5.12346`? Do you want to truncate values instead of rounding?

Comment: You shouldn't round your working values. You're just introducing errors to your calculations. Only round when you display to a user.

Comment: Also you could try `BigRational` library from Microsoft. As long as your calculations involve rational numbers you wont have any rounding at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental limitation of [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) types.. `double` is actually store internally as a sign exponent and mantissa, the exponent is base 2, so has a lot of trouble dealing with base 10..

The easiest solution is to use a base 10 64bit floating point type, namely `decimal`. Its still floating point, it still only limited precision but it is a lot friendly and more accurate to work with in a lot of cases

**Update**

If all you want to do is change the display output, you can either use rounding (which you know), or the appropriate [format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) with `string.format` `ToString` or string interpolation

**Example**

```
var number = 5.123455123321321;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("F3", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine($"{number:F3}");
// Displays 5.123
// Displays 5.123
```

Comment: @RonBeyer ahh ok, yes i see what you mean

Comment: Thank u so much, it is usefull.